# Spring dependency injection with duplicate beans and @Order annotation

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-bean

I am moderately confused about the DI injection mechanism in Spring when having multiple beans with the same name/type.
According to the exam slides from the Pivotal's "Core Spring" Course, Spring's behaviour with identical beans can be boiled down to:

- One can define same bean more than once
- Spring injects the bean defined last
- Using `@Order`, the loading mechanism (and thus, which bean is loaded last) can be modified

However, in the following example, Spring will ignore any `@Order` annotations and inject the bean from the Config class last mentioned in the `@Import` statement.
I'm therefore wondering whether the order of config classes in the `@Import` annotation overrides any `@Order` annotations. Or do I miss another important point?
Any hints are highly appreciated. Thanks Stack Overflow!

**Main Configuration class**

```java
@Configuration
@Import({RogueConfig.class,RewardsConfig.class})
public class TestInfrastructureConfig {
  // nothing interesting here, just importing configs
}
```

**RewardsConfig**

```java
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class RewardsConfig {
    @Bean
    public RewardNetwork rewardNetwork() {
        System.out.println("This Bean has been loaded from: " + this.getClass().getName());
        return new RewardNetworkImpl(null, null, null);
    }
}
```

**RogueConfig**

```java
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class RogueConfig {
    @Bean
    public RewardNetwork rewardNetwork() {
        System.out.println("This Bean has been loaded from: " + this.getClass().getName());
        return new RewardNetworkImpl(null, null, null);
    }
}
```

**Test class**

```java
public class RewardNetworkTests {

    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(TestInfrastructureConfig.class);
    }

    @Test
    void injectingRewardNetworkBeanWithOrdering() {
        RewardNetwork rewardNetwork = applicationContext.getBean(RewardNetwork.class);
        assertNotNull(rewardNetwork);
    }
}
```

No matter what values I assign `@Order`, or if I use ordering at all, the result will always be:

`This Bean has been loaded from: config.RewardsConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$62461c55`

The only way to change this is to modify the Import annotation in my `TestInfrastructureConfig` like so:

`@Import({RewardsConfig.class,RogueConfig.class})`, which yields:

`This Bean has been loaded from: config.RogueConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6ca7bc89`

I am wondering what needs to be done to allow the values defined in `@Order` to take any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to get Spring to use the `@Order` annotations by loading the configurations directly ( i.e. without the detour through a `@Configuration` class using `@Import`):

```java
@SpringJUnitConfig({RogueConfig.class, RewardsConfig.class})
public class CdiTest {

    @Test
    public void testCdiWithIdenticalBeans(@Autowired RewardNetwork rewardNetwork) {
        assertThat(rewardNetwork).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

With the `@Order(2)` annotation on the **RogueConfig** class, this bean got loaded last, as shown in stdout:

`This Bean has been loaded from: config.RogueConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$552b937f`

It seems that when using `@Import` in config classes it will load bean definitions in the order provided in the annotation, thus making any `@Order` annotations on the respective config classes useless.